# Mockito with Dependency Injection

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, mockito

I'm using Play Framework 2.5 and trying to test one of my DAO class based on the example [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWebServiceClients#testing-a-github-client).

But my class under test has dependency injection and I wonder how to mock it.

I tried to do something but it seems a bit clumsy, and I would like help to improve it.

Here is my code :

```
class MyController @Inject()(val mydao: MyDAOClass) extends Controller {

    def getData = Action { request =>
        mydao.fetchData
    }
}

class MyDAOClass @Inject()(ws: WSClient) {
    def urls(): List[String] = { List("url1", "url2") }

    // fetch data on different servers and should merge it.
    def fetchData(): Future[List[String]] = {
        val futures: List[Future[WSResponse]] = urls map { url =>
            ws.url(url + "/some/data").withRequestTimeout(10000.millis).get()
        }

        futures map { future =>

            future onComplete {
                case Success(resp) => println(resp.json)
                case Failure(t) => println("An error has occured: " + t.printStackTrace)
            }
        }

        Future(List())
    }
}
```

Here is my test code :

```
trait DAOTrait {
    def urls: List[String]
}

class MyDAOClass extends PlaySpec with MockitoSugar {

    "MyDAOClass" should {
        "get a list of data" in {
            Server.withRouter() {
                case GET(p"/url1/some/data") => Action {
                    Results.Ok(Json.arr(Json.obj("name" -> "data1")))
                }
            } { implicit port =>
                val mockMyDAOClass = mock[DAOTrait]
                when(mockMyDAOClass.urls) thenReturn List("url1")

                implicit val materializer = Play.current.materializer
                WsTestClient.withClient { client =>
                    val mydao = new MyDAOClass(client) {
                        override def urls = mockMyDAOClass.urls
                    }
                    val result = Await.result(
                        mydao.fetchData(), 10.seconds)
                    result mustEqual List("data1")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not finished in MyDAOClass, but it is enough to start implementing tests.

1) How to mock class that have dependency injection ?

2) When testing this code I have the following exception in MyDAOClass case Failure(t)

```
java.net.ConnectException: http://localhost:40183
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:137)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:683)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:604)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:564)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:425)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.doClose(AbstractNioChannel.java:462)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doClose(NioSocketChannel.java:236)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.doClose0(AbstractChannel.java:611)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:590)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:534)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.closeAll(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:361)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

but it should return Result.Ok instead.

3) Any advice welcome.

Comment: I don't know what the actual issue is, but dependency injection is clearly irrelevant here: the `MyDAOClass` instance used in the test is instanciated manually (with `new`), not by your DI framework. BTW, that seems perfectly reasonable for unit tests: you are trying to test a class in isolation, and I see no need to use DI for that.

Comment: Ok I thought the way I used mocking was a bit clumsy but I guess it is fine.  For the exception I think it is because I'm using a proxy.

Comment: For the actual mocking, I'd add that: 1. You don't need Mockito for this specific exemple (just use `override def urls = List("url1")` instead of `override def urls = mockMyDAOClass.urls`). 2. Doesn't the `urls` list need to be configurable? If so, consider configuring it in your `application.conf` and injecting a parameter of type `play.api.Configuration` (for unit testing, you can simply create a `Configuration` instance from a map or a list of key-value pairs).